# How to make my Mendeley publications searchable by Google?

Tags: google-search, cached-webpages

I tried everything: I uploaded my `.odt` and `.pdf` to my profile and I can see them, but when I look at my profile with Google:

`cache:http://www.mendeley.com/profiles/leonid-soshinskiy/`

my publications are not shown.

Comment: i just want to have my profile index and be visible with my publications

Comment: I just gave up and uploaded my works to https://zenodo.org — they also gave DOI record to these works. amazing